# Extjs dataStore after save

Tags: javascript, extjs, callback, datastore

I want to make a custom javaScript function call after my dataStore.save finished;
I have lookup for a afterSave callback for dataStore object, but it does not exists.
How can I make such call?

Answer (score 0):

So, you are talking about Ext JS 3?

In that case there is "save" event which is fired after save is completed.

Comment: yes I am using extjs 3; can you please show a piece of code, thanks.

Comment: Oh please, just RTFM: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/docs/?class=Ext.data.Store

Comment: it did not worked, documentation says it fires after the save is completed but, save operation did not occured at all.